# Bootstrap - How would I get all of the cards to be the same height?

Tags: html

I'm having an issue where the card div tags are not the same height. It seems to work when I use container, then row, then col then cards like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                Card content
            </div>
```

But I would prefer to have the whole lot in a card, I think think it looks a little better.

Thanks

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="card-deck">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                    Card Header
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Card body 5 
                                        <p> Text</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="card-deck">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                    Card Header
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Card body                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[How it looks on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATD2p.png)

Comment: `@Ashh` In *Bootstrap4* already predefined class `h-100` to set in `card-deck` class so no need to write `extra css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `height: 100%;` to `.card-deck` class, it will take the maximum height of cards and take the same height of both cards.
Try This:

```css
.card-deck{
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="card-deck">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                    Card Header
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Card body 5 
                                        <p> Text</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="card-deck">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                    Card Header
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Card body                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer to not change bootstrap's core css. I have found from @Raeesh Alam that I can use h-100. This answer does work though.